# How to get today as a string in Java 5?

Tags: java, java-5

For example for today I want string as "Sunday". I know how to do this in Java 6:

```
String day = Calendar.getInstance().getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

But this doesn't compile in Java 5. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use DateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat weekdayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
System.out.println(weekdayFormat.format(new Date()));
```

I haven't tried it but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (Calendar.getInstance ().get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) { ... }
```